# Bootstrap: Image height does not change if "col img-fluid" combined in a class along with the image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Image height does not change:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Override CSS -->
        <title>Image test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/990x600&text=Main+Image" class="col img-fluid" alt="Main Image"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Image height changes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Override CSS -->
        <title>Image test</title>
      </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/990x600&text=Main+Image" class="img-fluid" alt="Main Image"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Why does splitting the "col" and "img-fluid" make a difference to how responsive the image is? In the first case only the width of the image changes, In the second case: The width and the height of the image changes.

Comment: Both of your snippets work for me.

Comment: @Klooven Does the height of the image change too if you resize the browser?

Comment: Yep, it resizes in the way that the proportions are always the same.